# Assigning numerical value to answers to calculate results in Shiny

Tags: r, forms, shiny, calculation, shinyapps

I'm really new to R and shiny and have been asked to build something to assess environmental impact using a series of forms and then provide a report with the results and recommendations to improve. I have tried a number of different form builders but all of them don't perform the calculations or allow the user to see the results. So after much discussion we decided to use Shiny to make our own app as we have the capability to host it ourselves.

So far I've built the forms and got them to save locally to csv. What I need to do is assign a numerical value to the answers, then perform a calculation and display the results. I'm happy to dig around and play about with displaying the results. I'm just struggling to work out how to perform the calculations and assign the values.

Here's one of the forms:

```
#General Pharmacy form
                           tabPanel("General Pharmacy",
                                    tags$div(id= "form",

                                             #Gen Pharmacy Question 1
                                             radioButtons("genpharm1", "For trials which don't use an IxRS system, do you order drug:",
                                                          choices = c("Blindly (without consideration of patient numbers etc)", "Informed"),
                                                          selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, width = "600px"),

                                             #Gen Pharmacy Question 2
                                             radioButtons("genpharm2", "Do you recycle packaging?",
                                                          choices = c("Yes", "No"), selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, width = "600px"),

                                             #Gen Pharmacy Question 3
                                             radioButtons("genpharm3", "Do you use cost incentives to potentially improve efficient stock management by suppliers (eg. storage costs, per delivery etc…)",
                                                          choices = c("Yes", "No"), selected = NULL, inline = FALSE, width = "600px"))),
```

So for this example:

Question 1 - Blindly = 5 and Informed = 1

Question 2 - Yes = Question1*1 and No = Question1*2

Question 3 - Yes = Question2Result*1 and No = Question2Result*2

Then a result of 3 or less is a low impact and greater than 6 is a high impact.

Can anyone help? Even if it's pointing me in the right direction!

Thanks!

Comment: I would make a meta data table that has `questionNumber`, `questionAnswer`, `value` as the column headers. After recording their answers, use one of the `dplyr`'s join functions to get the associated value to their answer. If their score is just a product use `prod(df$value)`

Comment: Thanks Justin I'll give it a go!